# Not able to pass values to event handler on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have put a simple `eventhanlder` for my button click and passed two arguments upon clicking it. Hi is undefined error is throwing. If i put "Hi" (in double quotes) the event handler is doesnt fire at all. May i know what needs to be addressed.

I need this exactly as in my requirement I have to pass something like `<%#(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Category")%>` when a repeater row is clicked.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type ="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
        function OnClickeHandler(i, j) {
            debugger;
        }
    </script>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <input type ="button" id = "myButton" value = "Click" onclick = "OnClickeHandler(1,Hi)" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes to pass hi as string

Onclick="OnClickeHandler(1,'Hi')"

In HTML when you write any attributes you cover them with single quote of double quite

Like following both are valid.

```
onclick="abc()" 
onclick='abc()'
```

JavaScript can cover sting by both single quote or double quote and you also need to make sure that why passing string you don't break html.

All following are valid

```
onclick="abc('xyz')" 
onclick='abc("xyz")'
onclick="abc('x\'yz')"      ------ passing '  as string 
onclick='abc("xy\"z")'      ------ passing "  as string
```

You just need to make sure that what ever quote you are using to cover html attribute you don't use that in function call or value of attribute.

Comment: Thanks it solved it. How can i do this then, onclick="OnAddProductsClickHandler(<%#(String)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductId")%>, <%#(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Category")%>

Comment: something like this ->  '<%#(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Category")%>' . May i know why it expects only single quote instead of double quote

Comment: onclick="OnAddProductsClickHandler('<%#(String)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductId")%>', '<%#(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Category")%>')"    ----------- Just cover yout tags with '

Comment: modifying answer to explain why single quote. wait for a min

Comment: If this solved your problem and you wish, you can accept correct answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to put Hi in single quotes : 'Hi', as the call to the function is already in double quotes